# save an image using SDL_image?

Tags: c++, webos

how can i save a SDL_image to an image file ..
i have an image loaded using SDL IMG_Load() method .. i want to now save it in file ??
i dont want to display it on the surface .. just want to load an image manipulate its pixels and save it back ... dont want to load it on front end ??
so how i can save it to the file ?

was written in some forum
'Not much, at least with SDL_image. SDL_image has only functions for
reading images, not for writing images. SDL has SDL_SaveBMP(), but it's hmm
just for BMPs. You will need to use another library for writing JPEGs.'

[see here](http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=5776&sid=77778d6ffdada38675e4a50f7a0d7e9e)

thnks

Comment: So what's your target format? Do you want to write JPEG or just any image format?

Answer (score 1):

SDL_image has an undocumented `IMG_SavePNG()` and `IMG_SavePNG_RW()`.  The reason they are undocumented appears to be that they're limited to 32-bit RGBA images, but as this is far and away the most common format, it will likely be enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a third party library such as [corona](http://corona.sourceforge.net/).

```
corona::Image* image = corona::OpenImage( "c:/filename.ext", corona::PF_R8G8B8A8 );
// do some stuff with the image...
corona::SaveImage( "c:/filename.ext", PF_R8G8B8A8, image );
delete image;
```